# Rails Rspec error "undefined method" (railsturoial Chapter 10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm going through Michael Hartl's priceless tutorial and I got stuck with some Rspec errors. I've double checked everything but it seems like I'm still missing something. Here's what the error messages look like.

[image: error]

The thing that's bothering me the most is when I was generating the Microposts model I accidentally made a typo in one of the options so I did rails destroy model Microposts to undo the generate command before generating the model again. I'm wondering if that has anything to do with the errors I'm seeing.

I really wish to finish this tutorial ASAP so I can get on with building my own web application. ANY help would be appreciated.

Here's what my code looks like.

**micropost_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "MicropostPages" do
    subject {page}
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
        before {sign_in user}
        describe "micropost creation" do
            before {visit root_path}

            describe "with invalid information" do
                it "should not create a micropost" do
                expect {click_button "Post"}.not_to change(Micropost, :count)               
            end

            describe "error messages" do
                before {click_button "Post"}
                it {should have_content('error')}
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**microposts_controller.rb**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def create
        @micropost = current_user.micropost.build(params[:micropost])
        if @micropost.save
            flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end
end
```

**static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if signed_in?
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

end
```

**user.rb (User model)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy

  before_save {self.email.downcase!}
  before_save :create_remember_token

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
                    uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with this line:

```
@micropost = current_user.micropost.build(params[:micropost])
```

It should be:

```
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
```

You're using `micropost` when you should be using `microposts`.

Comment: Haha wow thanks a lot! will set as the answer once timer runs out.

Comment: @jkface: has the timer run out yet?